# Cannot import files from a folder

Tags: python, file

I have the following file structure:

```
dashboard
└── streamlit_app.py
    └── site
        ├── __init__.py
        └── app.py
```

```py
# streamlit_app.py
from site.app import start

if __name__ == '__main__':
  start()
```

```py
# app.py
import streamlit as st
import database as db

def start():
    st.set_page_config(
        page_title='henos',
        page_icon='https://imgur.com/a/urHOoK3',
        initial_sidebar_state='collapsed',
    )

    st.text('This website is under development, please wait until complete')
```

but when i run `streamlit_app.py` i get this error:
[image: error]

any help would be great

Comment: it seems that the imported `site` is from python standard library, but not the package. You can print `site.__file__` to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a module called 'site' and it's automatically imported during initialization.

Please check this link out to know more.

[site package in python](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/site.html)

#### Solution for your issue

> Please try to change the package name you made from 'site' to
> something else.